appengine-maven-plugin execution erroring out because Dockerfile not found
I am trying to deploy a java 11 application to google cloud app engine flex environment. Following is my app.yaml file:
runtime: java11
env: flex



handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6

endpoints_api_service:
  name: my-project-2-0-dev.appspot.com
  config_id: 2023-08-16r1

readiness_check:
  path: '/api/status/ready'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
liveness_check:
  path: '/api/status/live'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2


I am using the appengine-maven-plugin (version 2.7.0) to stage and deploy my project. On the project directory, here is the command which I run:
mvn package appengine:stage

And get following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.7.0:stage (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.7.0:stage failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Docker directory <project_path>/src/main/docker does not contain Dockerfile.

I do not intend to use a Docker container but still the plugin is looking for a Dockerfile. According to my understanding, it should be pulling from predefined runtime which google provides.
Also, I do not see this error when I use runtime: java

Have you checked this documentation on customizing the Java 8 / Jetty 9 runtime and naming and locating the Dockerfile wherein SDK-based Java tools such as the Maven, Gradle, Eclipse, and IntelliJ plugins require the Dockerfile?


Also, I do not see this error when I use runtime: java

This is the correct Java runtime for App Engine flex environment. If you want to specify the runtime_version, you should declare it under runtime_config. Your app.yaml should look like this:
runtime: java
env: flex

runtime_config:
    operating_system: "ubuntu22"
    runtime_version: "11"

You may refer to this documentation on Java runtime for App Engine flex environment for reference.
runtime: java11 only works for Java runtime for App Engine standard enviroment.

Thanks! I did try with that config. However, in the deployment logs I see the image was pulled from gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk@sha256:d25999c7cc570fa77d61a946399183174d20b1ce791bdf735fa151cfa4b41f07 - which is an image for java 8.
